# Iterating a generic list with super keyword

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have the following 2 class :

```
class A {
    public String toString(){
        return "A Class";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public String toString(){
        return "B Class";
    }
}
```

I have the following code which invokes a test method after adding some objects to a list :

```
List<B> myList = new ArrayList<B>();
myList.add(new B());
myList.add(new B());

testList(myList);
```

Now, my `testList` method is this :

```
public void testList(List<? super B> aList){        
        for(A myObject : aList){  //This is showing compiler error
            System.out.println(myObject);
        }  

       for(B myObject : aList){  //Even this is showing compiler error
            System.out.println(myObject);
        }

       for(Object myObject : aList){  //This works fine
            System.out.println(myObject);
        }
}
```

Why can't I use the reference type of `A` or `B` for iteration.

My list declaration in `testList` mehtod is with `super` keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List<? super B> aList` can be reference to `List<B>`, `List<A>` and `List<Object>` so in

```
for(A myObject : aList)
```

compiler can't let you use `A` as type because it will not handle `List<Object>` correctly since it can also contain elements which are not `A` or `B` since `Object` is super class of all classes, like `String` for instance (and using `A` to handle `String` would be wrong).

For same reason you can't use `B` (you wouldn't be able to correctly handle `List<A>`). Only `Object` is safe type here.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is declared so that it contains B elements (even if B's are A's, you can extract them as A's). So the only thing you can do is :

```
for(B myObject : aList){
  A a = myObject;
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

Now you can change your list to contains A's (B's are A's so you can put B's in the list):

```
List<A> myList = new ArrayList<A>();
myList.add(new B());
myList.add(new B());
```

and then

```
for(A myObject : aList){
  System.out.println(myObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

aList is defined with wildcard ? so the compiler does not know what type aList's elements are.

Try:

```
B object = aList.get(0);
```

Also fails. The compiler doesn't know what returns the get method.